# Why are these ODE constants real/complex?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I’m studying plane autonomous systems of ODEs. That is,

$\dot{x} = X(x,y), \dot{y} = Y(x,y)$

where $\dot{x}$ refers to differentiation with respect to $t$.

I’m analysing the solution of this system near a critical point by linearisation.

I have reached a stage where

$\underline{\dot{Z}}=M\underline{Z}$ where $M$ is a 2x2 matrix. Now it’s clear that if $M$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and  $\lambda_2$ say, then the solution to this is

$\underline{Z}=c_1\underline{Z_1}e^{\lambda_1t} + c_2\underline{Z_2}e^{\lambda_2t}$

for constants $c_i$.

Here’s where I’m confused. My lecture notes say that if the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are real then the constants $c_i$ and the $\underline{Z_i}$ are real. And if the eigenvalues are a complex conjugate pair then the $c_i$ and the $\underline{Z_i}$ are too. Why is this? I can’t see why?

Comment: If the $c_i$ and $Z_i$ don't satisfy those conditions, then $Z$ will take on nonreal values.

Comment: @eyeballfrog How? Sorry I’m struggling with this, could you spell it out? For the case of complex conjugate eigenvalues I only was able to conclude that $c_1\underline{Z_1}= c_2\underline{Z_2}$. How does this imply that the constants respectively are conjugates?

Answer (score 1):

$Z'= MZ\\
Z = e^{Mt}Z_0$

How do you exponentiate to a matrix power?  Or, what is $e^{Mt}?$

When $a$ is a real number, using the Taylor series.

$e^{at} = \sum \frac {(at)^n}{n!}$

And when $A$ is a matrix, we do the same thing.

$e^{Mt} = \sum \frac {(Mt)^n}{n!}$

Diagonalizing $M,$

$M = P^{-1}\Lambda P$ and $M^n = P^{-1}\Lambda^n P$

$PZ = \pmatrix{e^{\lambda_1 t}\\&e^{\lambda_2 t}}PZ_0$

If the eigenvalues are real then the matrix $P$ has real entries, as will $PZ_0$

If the eigenvalues are complex then the entries of P will be complex.  However, when we add these complex exponentials we will get sine and cosine functions with real coefficents.

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand why you are exponentiating a matrix at all :(

Comment: When you have a differential equation in a single variable $y' = ay$ the solution is $y=y_0e^{at}.$   Exponentiating is how you solve differential equations.  We have just replace the variable $a$ with the matrix $M.$